# How to design user registration process in an android app?

Tags: android

I tried to create application for Android and now i want to make registration. I was asked to talk to people around and get some answers:

```
1. make registration in browser and make link to it in application.  
2. Use Google account for registration (but i need phone number for registration so i can't get it from Google account).
```

But it's not looking nice. I see another way:

```
3. Make registration form inside application.
```

What do you think. How to make registration correctly?

Comment: You can make the registration inside the app but you will need to send the form to an external web service.  Vague answer for a vague question?

Comment: @clavio: I don't expect any code in answers. I just need to understand a right way. So answer is - registration into app it is a best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make registration from app using a web server of your own and using a web service send user details to your server in this way you can save user's information in your database which is there at server. You can keep your desired fields e.g. mobile number, email etc in Registration form which will be shown into the app and post data to server.